# Visual Studio Test Agent without TFS? (2010)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, load-testing

Is it possible to use the Visual Studio Test Agent and Test Controller without invloving TFS?

I'd like to run load tests on a web based system I'm developing, but my Test machines doesn't belong to the customer domain (where the TFS resides).

Answer (score 1):

I think it is possible.

- [When you install the `Test Controller` configure it for Load Testing.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff400223%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
- Add a rule to firewall of the machine that the Test Controller is installed for port 6901 (default for Test Controller).
- Install your `Test Agents` and assign them to your Test Controller.
- From your Visual Studio [add new Test Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256991%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and in the `Roles` tab choose `Remote Execution` and give the URL for the Controller.